# CSS - lost grid, remove margin from nested grid

Tags: css

I have a codepen here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxLzMV

Its a simple grid using lost.

The final column has a nested grid.

This nested grid has a right margin after the first column.

I have tried removing this using the cycle option but it wont work.

How can I remove this margin on the nested grid.

```
@use lost;

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  background: lightgrey;
}

.block{
  background: white;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

ul{
  list-style: none;
  lost-utility: clearfix;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mobile-arrow{
  display: none;
  float: right;
}

.info{
  padding: 10px;
}

.one{
  background: pink;
  lost-column: 2/5;
}

.two{
  background: pink;
  lost-column: 1/5;
}

.three{
  background: pink;
  lost-column: 2/5;
}

.three-inner__1{
  background: red;
  lost-column: 4/5 ;
}

.three-inner__2{
  background: green;
  lost-column: 1/5;
}

@media(max-width: 650px){
  .mobile-arrow{
    display: block;
  }
  .one{
    lost-column: 3/5;
  }
  .two{
    lost-column: 2/5 2; 
  }
  .three{
    margin-top: 10px;
    lost-column: 1/1;
    lost-move: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the margin by using a third argument:

```
.three-inner__1{
   background: red;
   lost-column: 4/5 0 0px;
}
```

[Lost documentation on column](http://lostgrid.org/docs.html#lost-column)

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMNpmb)